# How to Avoid Calling hasNextLine() twice?

Tags: java, string, io

I am reading a file that has some blank lines, my code is structured as:

```
 while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.readLine();
            if (line.length() != 0) {
                int recordsNumber = Integer.parseInt(line);
                ...
```

But according to the tests, I unnecessarily called hasNextLine on every line in the file twice. Why is it so?

Comment: The code looks ok. If you want help solving it, you need to provide more information, including the input file content and possibly more code. First guess would be the file has extra newline characters in the file, causing it to be treated as additional lines. like: "\n\n"

Comment: What is `input`? Is it a `BufferedReader`? Is it a `Scanner`? ... I can't think which class has both `hasNextLine()` and `readLine()`.